# Pandas - Move data in one column to the same row in a different column

Tags: pandas

I have a df which looks like the below, There are 2 quantity columns and I want to move the quantities in the "QTY 2" column to the "QTY" column

Note: there are no instances where there are values in the same row for both columns (So for each row, QTY is either populated or else QTY 2 is populated. Not Both)

**DF**

| Index | Product | QTY | QTY 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Shoes | 5 |  |
| 1 | Jumpers |  | 10 |
| 2 | T Shirts |  | 15 |
| 3 | Shorts | 13 |  |

**Desired Output**

| Index | Product | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Shoes | 5 |
| 1 | Jumpers | 10 |
| 2 | T Shirts | 15 |
| 3 | Shorts | 13 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['QTY'] = np.where(df['QTY'].isnull(), df['QTY 2'], df['QTY'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df["QTY"] = df["QTY"].fillna(df["QTY 2"], downcast="infer")
```

filling the gaps of QTY with QTY 2:

```py
In [254]: df
Out[254]:
   Index   Product   QTY  QTY 2
0      0     Shoes   5.0    NaN
1      1   Jumpers   NaN   10.0
2      2  T Shirts   NaN   15.0
3      3    Shorts  13.0    NaN

In [255]: df["QTY"] = df["QTY"].fillna(df["QTY 2"], downcast="infer")

In [256]: df
Out[256]:
   Index   Product  QTY  QTY 2
0      0     Shoes    5    NaN
1      1   Jumpers   10   10.0
2      2  T Shirts   15   15.0
3      3    Shorts   13    NaN
```

`downcast="infer"` makes it "these look like integer after NaNs gone, so make the type integer".

you can drop QTY 2 after this with `df = df.drop(columns="QTY 2")`. If you want one-line is as usual possible:

```py
df = (df.assign(QTY=df["QTY"].fillna(df["QTY 2"], downcast="infer"))
        .drop(columns="QTY 2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do ( I am assuming your empty values are empty strings):

```
df = df.assign(QTY= df[['QTY', 'QTY2']].
               replace('', 0).
               sum(axis=1)).drop('QTY2', axis=1)
```

print(df):

```
    Product  QTY
0     Shoes    5
1   Jumpers   10
2  T Shirts   15
3    Shorts   13
```

If the empty values are actually NaNs then

```
df['QTY'] = df['QTY'].fillna(df['QTY2']) #or

df['QTY'] = df[['QTY', 'QTY2']].sum(1)
```

Comment: you can still `df[["QTY", "QTY 2"]].sum(1)` if NaN

Comment: yes sure we can do that. updated.